# Pagina duplica encabezados con peticion AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

Tengo un problema con una pagina que es cargada a través de `AJAX` para realizar una búsqueda, estoy trabajando con una master page para tener fijo el encabezado de mi pagina pero cuando hago la llamada a la pagina que llamo mediante AJAX me duplica el encabezado, no se por que si estilos y scripts están en mi master page

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

master page

```html
@CODE
         Dim usu = Session("usu")
    Dim pass = Session("pass")
    If usu = "" Then
    @<script>
         alert("Ha finalizado tu sesión")
         window.location.href = "../index.vbhtml";
    </script>
    End If
End CODE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@PageData("Title")</title>
        @RenderSection("head", required:=false)
            <!-- bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="../content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!-- material icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paprika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <!--Estilos propios-->
    <link href="../content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../content/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/validacion.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                        locale: 'es',
                        dayViewHeaderFormat: 'YYYY',
                        viewMode: 'months',
                        format: "MM/YYYY"
                    });


                    $('#btnBuscarcomisiones').click(function () {
                        var cargando = $("#muestraBuscacomisionHoy").html("<center><img  src='../images/carga.gif'/><center>");


                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'buscaComisionesAchip.vbhtml',
                            data: { "valorBuscado": $("#datetimepicker10").val() },
                            beforesend: function () {
                                cargando.show();
                                //$("#muestraBuscacomisionHoy").hide();
                            },
                            success: function (resultado) {
                                cargando.hide();
                                //$("#muestraBuscacomisionHoy").hide();
                                $('#muestraBuscacomision').hide().html(resultado).fadeIn(900);
                            }

                        });
                    });
                });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- Barra de navegacion-Menu -->
    <div class="header">
        <ul>
  @Code
   If usu <> "capturas" Then
   @<li class="cargador"><a href="../Cargadorachip/Cargador.aspx" target="_blank" class="boton">Cargador</a></li>          
   End If
  End Code           
            <li class="titulo">
                <h2>Comisiones Amigo Chip</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="logout">Usuario : @usu</li>
            <li class="salir"><a href="logout"><b>Salir</b></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

pagina en donde que es llamada por AJAX

```html
@code 
    Layout = "../_Layout.vbhtml"
end code


        @Code
            Dim valorBuscado, mesBuscado, añoBuscado As String
            'valorBuscado = Request.Form("valorBuscado")
            valorBuscado = "01/2016"
            mesBuscado = Month(valorBuscado)
            añoBuscado = Year(valorBuscado)
            
            Response.Write(valorBuscado + "tu mes es " + mesBuscado + " tu año es " + añoBuscado)
            

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            
            Dim db = Database.Open("REP")
            'variable QueryString - almacenar el numero pagina
            Dim pagina = Request.QueryString("pagina")
            'Si pagina es nulo o vacio , se inicializa en 1
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pagina) Then
                pagina = 1
            Else
                'Si-NO se asigna el valor QueryString("pagina") a pagina
                pagina = Request.QueryString("pagina")
            End If
            'Obtener pagina siguiente a la actual
            Dim sig = pagina + 1
            'Obtener pagina anterior a la actual
            Dim ant = pagina - 1
            Dim activo = pagina
            'Query para obtener resultados por paginación

            Dim consulta = db.Query("with tablapag as (select COM.CREATEDATE, FAC.SERIE_INICIAL,FAC.FECHA_FACTURA AS FECHA_FACTURA_F,FAC.FACTURA,COM.ICCID_19,COM.ARTICULO,FAC.CELULAR,FAC.ESTATUS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ESTATUS) as rownum from COMISION_AM FAC LEFT JOIN COMISION_AMI COM ON FAC.SERIE_INICIAL  COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = SUBSTRING(COM.ICCID_19,1,18) WHERE MONTH(FAC.FECHA_FACTURA)='" + mesBuscado + "' AND YEAR(FAC.FECHA_FACTURA)='" + añoBuscado + "') select * from tablapag WHERE rownum between(@0-1)* 500 + 1 and (@0 * 500)", pagina)
            'query para obtener el total de paginas, entre el numero de registros a mostrar por pagina

            Dim paginas = db.QuerySingle("select  COUNT(*)/500 total_filas from COMISION_AM FAC LEFT JOIN COMISION_AMI COM ON FAC.SERIE_INICIAL  COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = SUBSTRING(COM.ICCID_19, 1, 18) where MONTH(FAC.FECHA_FACTURA)='" + mesBuscado + "' AND YEAR(FAC.FECHA_FACTURA)='" + añoBuscado + "'")
            Dim pags = paginas.total_filas + 1
            Response.Write(pagina)
            Dim count = 1



            
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''            

                @If consulta.Count > 0 Then 'Validar que consulta no venga vacío
                    
        @<div class="tabla" id="content">
            <table id="" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>SERIE INICIAL</th>
                        <th>FECHA FACTURA FONIX</th>
                        <th>FECHA CREACION</th>
                        <th>FACTURA</th>
                        <th>ICCID_19</th>
                        <th>ARTICULO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @For Each row In consulta
                        @<tr>
                            <td>@row.rownum</td>
                            <td>@row.SERIE_INICIAL</td>
                            <td>@row.FECHA_FACTURA_FONIX</td>
                            <td>@row.CREATEDATE</td>
                            <td>@row.FACTURA</td>
                            <td>@row.ICCID_19</td>
                            <td>@row.ARTICULO</td>
                        </tr>
        Next
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
                    
                    
                Else

                    Response.Write("No hay ningún registro encontrado")
                    

                End If
            
        End Code


            <!-- Paginador -->
    <ul class="pagination" id="uno">
        @Code 'Si pagina es mayor a 1 se mostrara botón "<"(anterior) para ir una pagina atrás
            If pagina > 1 Then
            @<li><a href="buscaComisionesAchip?pagina=@ant">&laquo;</a></li>
            End If
        End Code

        @For num = 1 To pags 'for para generar las paginas
            @<li><a href="buscaComisionesAchip?pagina=@num">@num</a></li>
        Next
        @Code 'si pagina es menor al total de paginas se mostrar el botón ">" para ir una pagina adelante
            If pagina < pags Then
            @<li><a href="buscaComisionesAchip?pagina=@sig">&raquo;</a></li>
            End If
        End Code

    </ul>

        <!-- -->
```

Comment: Hola Ivxn. El usuario @MarkSnizhysnki pregunta si ya lo pudiste solucionar. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Es probable que la página que pretendes cargar en el div a través de Ajax, contenga también la cabecera, de ser asi si tendrias dos opciones:

1. En la página B, página que vas a cargar en el div de la página A, eliminale el contenido que se repite, (el header imagino).
2. Una vez cargada la página mediante ajax, utiliza javascript y elimina el div o header que se repite  (el repetido).
   Puedes utilizar algo como:

   ```
   $('#idHeaderB').remove()
   ```